# How to properly populate javascript objects from global variables

Tags: javascript, php, html

I started playing with the Instagram API. The following code snippet retrieves the Instagram ID of a username.

```
<?php 
    $username = "[SOME-USERNAME]";
    $client_id = "[CLIENT-ID]";
    $access_token = "[ACCESS-TOKEN]";
    $json_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=".$username."&client_id=".$client_id;
    $json = file_get_contents($json_url);
    $links = json_decode($json);

    echo $links->data[0]->username."'s Instagram ID : ".$links->data[0]->id."\n";
?>
```

Then I want to use that ID to generate the user's Instagram album via [Instafeed.js](http://instafeedjs.com/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var user_id = "<?php echo $links->data[0]->id; ?>";
    var access = "<?php echo $access_token; ?>";

    var userFeed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        //userId: 0,
        //accessToken: ' ',
        links: true,
        resolution: 'standard_resolution'
    });
    userFeed["userId"] = user_id;
    userFeed["accessToken"] = access;
    userFeed.run();
</script>
```

The problem is the function run() doesn't seem to work when I populate the object from global variables.

Comment: There's this thing in your browser called "view source." Use that to check that the JS didn't get misformatted by what was in the variables you printed.

Comment: Any errors in browser console? Have you tried wrapping all that code in window.onload?

Comment: echo it after using json_encode(), in case there are quotes or escaped chars

Comment: @developerwjk I viewed the source, put some alerts to test variables. Everything seems to go as planned, except for the final run() function.

Comment: @leo.fcx it says userId not specified.

Comment: @dandavis still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing a little bit the library code, the way that you set the `userId` and other options is not correct. Properties should be set inside  `options` object.

Use:

```
userFeed.options.userId = user_id;
userFeed.options.accessToken = access;
userFeed.run();
```

Instead of:

```
userFeed["userId"] = user_id;
userFeed["accessToken"] = access;
userFeed.run();
```

Comment: This solved the main problem which was accessing the object properties. I also had to convert the userId to integer as I didn't pay attention to the type specifications.
Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is build your JSON object that you are passing into the `Instafeed` object using the variables you get from PHP

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userFeed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: <?= json_encode($links->data[0]->id) ?>,
        accessToken: <?= json_encode($access_token) ?>,
        links: true,
        resolution: 'standard_resolution'
    });
    userFeed["userId"] = user_id;
    userFeed["accessToken"] = access;
    userFeed.run();
</script>
```